# Separate JavaScript document talk to GWT Application

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a JavaScript document which I've created with some complex functionality which relies on a couple third party JavaScript libraries being included.

My goal is to have it so that GWT can interact with my script and vice versa. I've tried to create a GWT wrapper which uses JSNI but had problems trying to get communication back from JavaScript (Embedded in my index.html - which is blank apart from the code to inject GWT) to my GWT application.

For my second attempt I've created a servlet on the GWT server side which I can communicate with via JSON although this looks like it will work it seems quite hacky having to rebuild many of the framework technologies which GWT has already fixed.

So my question is what's the easiest way to get two way communication from my JavaScript to GWT without the initial call coming from GWT (If possible)?

Comment: Apologies if this is a bit complex, I've been trying to find a work around for this problem for the last couple of weeks - Just wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: What code did you try for your JNI?  You should not have any trouble with it so there must have been something wrong with your implementation.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that a completely stand alone javascript file can't talk to GWT? and that the only way javascript to GWT communication can be achieved is by initialising a call from a javascript "snippet" which is firstly being called from Java?